# Character arrays assignment and comparison in C

Tags: c

What does this statement mean in C language (assuming s1 and s2 are character arrays)?

```
(s1[i] = s2[i]) != '\0'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering `string`s are `\0` terminated by the standard.

```
(s1[i] = s2[i]) != '\0'
```

it will assign `s2[i]` to `s1[i]` then it will compare whether assigned value is `\0` or not.

It is usually used to break the loop while copying contents from one string to another.

Comment: The style of coding is often seen in loop control such as `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: This code might be part of a `strcpy` implementation `char * strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2) { size_t i; for(i = 0; (s1[i] = s2[i]) != '\0'; i++); return s1; }`